# Docker compose to start container when another stops

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm wondering, is there any option to start containers one by one in Docker Compose?
E.g I want to start DB container and special container to init this DB, and main application should be started after init container finished. 
Or I want to perform compilation in one container, then packing in another.
In Kubernetes there is something called "init pods", similar to this, as far as I understand. Is there any alternative in Docker Compose?

Comment: Are you looking something similar to [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for)?

Comment: Actually not. I want to create chain of containers. E.g I'm starting DB engine, thae doing initial db import, when import complete - starting my application. I can implement this logic inside my app, but I think there should be another option.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here fundamentally does not refer to as service. As detailed in [comment](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896#issuecomment-322285976), service is a long-running process that interacts with other services to form an application.

I suggest you take a look at [dobi](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896#issuecomment-255184536) It runs project tasks (like running a shell, running unit tests, running migration).

There's an example of the compose integration and running db migrations here: https://github.com/dnephin/dobi/tree/master/examples/init-db-with-rails

Answer (score -1):

Well why don't you use depends_on tag

```
   depends_on: 
      - <YourDockerContainer>
```

Looks at this example below where

Kibana is dependant on ElasticSearch and fluentd, while Elasticsearch is dependant on fluentd using depends_on tag

```
 fluentd:
    image: fluentd

 elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
 depends_on: 
   - fluentd  

 kibana:
    image: kibana
 depends_on: 
   - fluentd
  - elasticsearch
```

Order of Start will be

1> fluentd

2> elasticsearch

3> kibana

Comment: This only indicates that kibana container will not be started before fluentd container. I need to start container only after another container exited.